# Should I use a single ODBC environment for multiple connections?

Tags: c++, c, odbc

I'm learning ODBC, and my application needs to use multiple connections concurrently. Should I be allocating a single environment, and then multiple connections from this?

Or an environment for each connection?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is anything to be gained from creating multiple environments unless you are going to change something at the environment level e.g., call SQLSetEnvAttr with different arguments on each environment handle.